# Display current time in ASP.net and have it ticking

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, time, timer

I have a requirement in my application to show date and time.
I am using Ajax in my .net application to do this.

Currently I have this code

```
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Timer ID="UpdateTimer" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick" />
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="TimedPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateTimer" EventName="Tick" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="DateStampLabel" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It is working just fine besides a one second delay when you refresh the page. My question is this, is this the best way to accomplish this? I could perhaps get away with not showing seconds...that may not be too important. If I do that how should I do it?

Here is the codebehind...

```
Protected Sub UpdateTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    DateStampLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to display server time or client time? (if the latter, using javascript only solution would be a better choice)

Comment: Alternatively, show the server's time in the returned HTML, but use Javascript to compare that time to the local machines and then update it every second based on the local clock, so it will display the server's time without needing to poll it.

Comment: Good question. It really doesn't matter since this will be used on the intranet for a company. I'm unsure...I guess client may be best...

Comment: Just for anyone that references this in the future, Jupaol is correct in that a Client-Side solution is more efficient in almost all aspects. However, to address your issue with the one second delay when the page is refreshed, you can set DateStampLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString() inside of the Page_Load event, or any of the other Page Events that are executed before the page is sent to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you to do that, since every time you want to refresh the timer (every second) you are actually hitting the server in order to display the timer. Obviously the performance implications of this approach are negative

And also you are using an *evil* `UpdatePanel` which means you are executing the whole page life-cycle every time.

You could accomplish the same behavior if you rely on the client browser:

```
$('#digital-clock').clock({offset: '0', type: 'digital'});
<ul id="digital-clock" class="digital">
  <li class="hour"></li>
  <li class="min"></li>
  <li class="sec"></li>
  <li class="meridiem"></li>
</ul>
```

Reference:

http://joaquinnunez.cl/jquery-clock-plugin/